# Редактирование ресурсов из программы

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток.
В программе для выполнения лабораторных работ существует набор из уже готовых лаб с занесёнными туда необходимыми данными. Файлы самих лаб лежат в ProgramName.Properties.Resources. Извлекаются во временную папку, при закрытии программы удаляются.
Но со временем вполне может возникнуть необходимость в изменении каких-либо данных, либо в добавлении новых лаб. В связи с этим вопрос - можно ли как-нибудь добавить новый, либо хотя бы перезаписать старый файл в ресурсах программы? 
Возможность создания файла через BinaryWriter уже есть, мне интересны способы именно ковыряния в ресурсах программы без последующей перекомпиляции. 
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы что-то делаете не так. Ресурсы не предназначены для их редактирования вручную, без перекомпиляции. (Хотя это возможно, если помучиться.) Если вам нужно редактирование данных, поместите их просто в отдельный файл, и там редактируйте на здоровье (или просто подменяйте этот файл на другой).

Comment: Я не вижу смысла в этом, поскольку существуют гораздо более эффективные и элегантные способы решения данного вопроса. А так может данная статья Вам поможет: [Создание вспомогательных сборок](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/21a15yht(v=vs.90).aspx)